# Configuration Error : Unrecognized attribute 'maxBufferSize'

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, web-config, service-model

I had a recent change in my web.config file of a wcf REST service, I just added `maxBufferSize="10485760"` property to it. Please find the code segment below...

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:04:00" 
                 openTimeout="00:04:00" receiveTimeout="00:04:00" sendTimeout="00:04:00" 
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode=
                 "StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="10485760" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                 maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                 maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:04:00" enabled="false" />
 </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

After making that change, the application is not working, It is throwing following exception.

> *Configuration Error Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately. Parser Error Message: Unrecognized
>   attribute 'maxBufferSize'. Note that attribute names are
>   case-sensitive.*

If anyone could help on this, that would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whole your problem is, that wsHttpBinding binding does not have any maxBufferSize property. This property is available in basicHttpBinding for instance. I recomend you to use Visual Studio to modify your bindings in web.config file instead of modifying it directly. Plus you can see available properties for next time.
[image: ScreenShot]

The wsHttpBinding has property MaxBufferPoolSize, which is something slightly different then MaxBufferSize. Please [look at this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6e234d3-942f-4e9d-8470-32618d3f3212/maxbufferpoolsize-vs-maxbuffersize) to understand the difference